# Apache ProxyPass worker name too long

Tags: php-fpm, ubuntu-14.04, proxypass

I'm passing my php files to php5-fpm within my Apache .conf file however I'm receiving an error message when restarting the Apache server:

> ProxyPass worker name
>   (fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/averyverylong/directoryname/tothe/www/working/directory/$1)
>   too long.

I'm passing php files to php-fpm via:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ \
  fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/averyverylong/directoryname/tothe/www/working/directory/$1
```

Obviously if I shorten the directory name, it works fine. However this isn't really an option.

Running:
Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu 14.04)
PHP5-FPM

I'm stumped on this and have spent the entire day trying to figure out a workaround for it. My server skills aren't the strongest, any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you could create a symbolic link with a shorter name to the longer path.  For example:

```
ln -s /home/averyverylong/directoryname/tothe/www/working/directory \
  /var/www/html/shortcut
```

Then use

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/shortcut
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the workaround, I can confirm the symlink does get around the length issue. I just wish there was a more elegant way

Answer (score 3):

An alternate (and in my opinion, more elegant) solution would be to use the RewriteEngine, as is discussed in this Apache bug report https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53218

```
# This directive must come before the following one in order
# block access to arbitrary URIs on the origin server!
# As an alternative one can also use "RewriteRule /UNUSED - [F]"
ProxyPass /UNUSED !

# Configure a connection pool for the origin server
# http://myserver.example.org:9081
ProxyPass /UNUSED fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000

RewriteEngine On

# Proxy "/long" to a long URI on the origin server,
# [P] flag at end of line is important
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/averyverylong/directoryname/tothe/www/working/directory/$1 [P]
```

This allows you to continue to use the same file structure without the overhead of manually creating symlinks everywhere (which also will not work on Windows machines). I believe that the worker name limit is being raised in a future version of Apache, but for now this workaround should give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to symfony documentation in apache >=2.4.9 you can use

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    # 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
    # SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"

    # Else we can just use a tcp socket:
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#php-fpm-with-apache-2-2

https://serversforhackers.com/video/apache-and-php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

Bug filed for Ubuntu. Please indicate that you're affected and request update for Trusty. Getting the fix into a stable release will require some input from the community.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/apache2/+bug/1668474